# Multiple Row Edit Functionality in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to implement an edit row functionality in a react grid. I have attached 2 links. Link 1 is the GIF which shows the functionality that I have implemented using the below code.(For privacy reasons I cannot publish the actual code)

Link 2 is the functionality I am trying to achieve! How shall I do that?

```
 return (
  <>
    <p>Sample Row Field</p>
    {editId === Id && editRow === true ? (
      <select options={options} handleChange={handleChange} />
    ) : (
      existingRowValue
    )}
  </>
);
```

Link 1 - The Functionality I have (Individual Row)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJEL5.gif

Link 2 - The Functionality I want (Multiple Rows)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7ppb.gif

Comment: Am I right to assume that editId is a state that changes depending on the on the row's edit button that it is clicked? If that's the case then your code works exactly as it should. Checks if the editId equals the row's id and if it doesnt it displays the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd assume `editId` is a local state variable, same for `editRow`
So what you'd need to do is change `editId` into a state called `editIds` as an **array** (because you want to edit multiple rows, not just one), and replace `editId === Id` with `editIds.includes(Id)`

- **onEditClick:** should add the rowId into this state, like `setEditIds(...editIds, rowId)`
- **onSave/CancelClick:** should remove the id from the state, like: `setEditIds(editIds.filter((id) => id !== rowId))`

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me achieve the functionality I wanted.  However I do have a follow-up question!     How do I differentiate one state value from the other! For example I am looking to edit a name! I have a [name, setName] = useState(). I set the value of name via a onChange handler. In a grid, how do I differentiate the edited name from say row 1 to row 2?

Answer (score 0):

I think following code sample will give you an idea of how you can achieve this when you move your **editId** to a local component state.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/hardcore-sid-pythne?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark